# List style giving different appearance in different browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

I can't figure out why my 'list-style: disc' gives different appearance in different browser. See http://www.galadadatingandrelating.com/ under the aqua colored 'Contact Us' area there are 3 li element. -

```
If you want to join us sailing as an individual or a couple, at any time, contact us here.

If you have a dating and relating question/dilemma feel free to send it here. We may reply to you personally or we may cover it in a blog.

If you have a question on any of the services, packages, next sailing and exotic islands trips – feel free to ask us here.
```

Now they show a disc just before them in Firefox but in Chrome the disc is totally on the left.

Why does the Chrome browser show this incorrectly?

Comment: Something in your CSS is changing the list-style-position between the two browsers. Both do the same positioning natively. Can't see exactly what is changing yours.

Comment: yes i have noticed that in chrome browser the li are becoming full width. Can't figure out how they are becoming full width. This is not so in firefox. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Add `list-style-position: inside;` to the `<li>` elements:

```
.line-wrap ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

**A list example to see the problem and solution in action:**

```css
ul#one, ul#two {
  text-align:center;
}
ul#two {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul id="one">
  <li>List</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>One</li>
</ul>
<ul id="two">
  <li>List</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

> **from the specification about the `inside`:**
>   The marker box is placed as the first inline box in the principal block box, before the element's content and before any :before pseudo-elements. CSS 2.1 does not specify the precise location of the marker box.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position

**Explanation:**
On Google Chrome the default value of the `list-style-position` is `outside`:
[image]
On Mozilla Firefox too, it seems Firefox interprets this rule a little bit different!

Comment: thanks it solved my problem but what exactly is inside property?